# why use Invoke when I can write the code inline?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is with reference to a winforms app i am working on. I am a little confused with Invoke.

I know beginInvoke is async and invoke is sync. beginInvoke makes sense, if you want a block of code to work async and let the UI be responsive but why would I want to use Invoke if the process is sync ? I could get the same result with writing the code inline right ?

Comment: Only if your code is already running on the UI thread. If it's running on some other thread, then `Invoke` is a way of marshalling that call onto the UI thread, which is highly useful.

Comment: Invoke marshalls the call to right thread but blocks the calling one (for ex your background thread).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not exactly. `Invoke` also makes sure the code runs *in the right thread*.

Its main use is calling Invoke from a background thread and having the code run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

`Invoke` is typically used in this context:

```
Control.Invoke(...);
```

Where `Control` is actually a control. The important thing here is that the execution **takes place on the UI thread**.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks BradleyDotNET.